# Cascading if statement not working

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am getting the compile error "Else without If" in the following part of my code. What's the issue and how do I fix it?

```
    If InStr(1, Worksheets("Raw data").Cells(i, 3), "1M") Then Call RowCopyPaste("AS-001", i, counter1M)
    counter1M = counter1M + 1

    ElseIf InStr(1, Worksheets("Raw data").Cells(i, 3), "2M") Then Call RowCopyPaste("AS-001", i, counter2M)
    counter2M = counter2M + 1

    ElseIf InStr(1, Worksheets("Raw data").Cells(i, 3), "3M") Then Call RowCopyPaste("AS-001", i, counter3M)
    counter3M = counter3M + 1

    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An If comparison can live on the same line as a single command but not as you are doing it. Your two-commands-per-condition should be more like the following.

```
If InStr(1, Worksheets("Raw data").Cells(i, 3), "1M") Then
    Call RowCopyPaste("AS-001", i, counter1M)
    counter1M = counter1M + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Worksheets("Raw data").Cells(i, 3), "2M") Then
    Call RowCopyPaste("AS-001", i, counter2M)
    counter2M = counter2M + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Worksheets("Raw data").Cells(i, 3), "3M") Then
    Call RowCopyPaste("AS-001", i, counter3M)
    counter3M = counter3M + 1
End If
```

Something like the following could live by itself but not with other `ElseIf` commands.

```
If InStr(1, Worksheets("Raw data").Cells(i, 3), "1M") Then Call RowCopyPaste("AS-001", i, counter1M)
```

You might want to try this as a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) if you have any more conditions to cover.

Comment: Good answer. Maybe while your at it you could mention how `Call` can be dispensed with since that would make the code a little more idiomatic.

Comment: While the `Call` is unnecessary and a bit of a throwback, programmers will use it to help make their own code more readable to themselves. I think perhaps this comment and yours should serve to let others know that they can dispense with `Call` as long as they also remove the brackets surrounding the parameters.

Comment: VBA's way of calling subs (without `Call`) *is* a bit odd and takes some getting used to. You are right that it is probably sufficient to leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can replace the nested If with [Select Case](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php) and even the Instr() with [Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator:

```
 Select Case True

    Case Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, 1) Like "*1M*"
       Call RowCopyPaste("AS-001", i, counter1M)
       counter1M = counter1M + 1

    Case Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, 1) Like "*2M*"
       Call RowCopyPaste("AS-001", i, counter2M)
       counter2M = counter2M + 1

    Case Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, 1) Like "*3M*"
       Call RowCopyPaste("AS-001", i, counter3M)
       counter3M = counter3M + 1

    Case Else
       '...

End Select
```